# Как скопировать все файлы и папки

Tags: python-3.x

Необходимо скопировать всё из одной директории(независимо файл это или папка) в другую. Внимание вопрос! Как это сделать? Желательно без установки посторонних модулей...

Comment: Можно батником все сделать

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shutil.html#copytree-example